# PHP force download, not sending full binary files

Tags: php, pdf, header, stream, download

I'm creating a protected file download system for an e-commerce website. I am  using PHP to authenticate that a user is logged in and owns the product before it is downloaded. I am using the example provided by the [PHP.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2400) but have run into an error serving both PDF and PNG files.

It has worked at one point, during development. Now that we've gone live,  it seems to have broke... Fortunately the website is not running full-force at the moment so it's not a huge issue right now.

**What is happening:**

You visit the download URL. You are verified as an owner of the product, and the download starts. Everything appears to be normal, reviewing the headers everything looks OK. The header states the content length is "229542" (224.16kb), which looks OK.

**The problem:**

When the download  completes, the file size is only 222 **bytes**. There are no errors displayed, and no PHP errors/warnings/notices are being sent in the file or browser. It's as if PHP is being terminated, but without any warnings. Even if I turn debugging on, I don't see  any warnings.

The source file [looks like this](http://radleygh.com/images/notepad++_2013-246-14-04-39-11.png) (in Notepad++, it's a PDF so it's binary)

When downloaded, it [looks like this](http://radleygh.com/images/notepad++_2013-246-14-05-01-83.png) (Only 7 lines, compared to 2554)

**My guess:**

I am fairly certain the issue is header related. Maybe caused by a plugin? This shows up in Chrome's networking console:

[image]

**Response Headers:**

Below are the response headers. The "Connection: close" concerns me. I am not sending that header. I'm guessing it is sent by the `exit` command.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close 
Content-Description:File Transfer
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="workbook.pdf"
Content-Length:229542
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Tue, 03 Sep 2013 21:16:14 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:public
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PleskLin
```

**I have also tried:**

1. Turning on PHP debugging to get some sort of error/warning, but I don't get anything useful in browser or in the downloaded file source.
2. Outputting to the browser, rather than streaming. The file is still cut short, I would expect a PDF would try to display in the browser's PDF reader - but it doesn't even try. Just a white page with a bunch of unknown symbols.
3. Using +rb read mode, using `fopen( $file['file'], 'rb' ); echo fread( $fh, filesize( $file['file'] ) ); fclose( $fh );`
4. Using `ignore_user_abort(true)` and `set_time_limit(0)` to no effect (also tried set_time_limit(10000) just for in case, still nothing)
5. Sending a `.txt` file. **This worked.** I tried with a simple 5-byte text file, and again with an 86.3kb file. Both appear to have come out the same as they went in. So it must be related to binary files...

---

```
/* --- This is what the $file variable looks like:
$file = array(
  [file] => /var/www/vhosts/my-website/uploads/workbook.pdf
  [type] => application/pdf
  [filesize] => 229542
  [filename] => workbook.pdf
  [upload_date] => 1377278303
);
*/

// Stream the file to the user
if (file_exists($file['file'])) {
  header_remove(); // Remove any previously set header
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: ' . $file['type']);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($file['file']);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: You probably should be doing `readfile($file);` and not `readfile($file['file']);` I've seen this type of thing happen before.

Comment: Not in this case,  $file is just an array. $file['file'] (as confusing as it is) contains the actual filename. I did try using `fopen` and using a file handle with `readfile`, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: And have you tried `readfile($filename);` ?

Comment: And this `header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);` should resemble something like this `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));` that may be the issue here. It's not delivering full content.

Comment: What happens if you try it without `Content-Length` header, or what happens if you set `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` ?

Comment: I suggest you change all your `$file` to something else. It may be conflicting with `[file]`

Comment: Glavic, I was actually using `application/octet-stream` earlier but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Changing the content-length does not seem to affect the file size either, it's always 222 bytes for some reason. For clarity's sake, if I remove ALL of the headers, the file still downloads at 222 bytes. It must be something else...

Comment: Fred, I do not believe the issue is relating to my variables at all. I have tested the output and all appear to be correct. I have tried  inserting them as simple strings as well, just in case they were causing an issue, and I get the same issue. This is something more in-depth, I think. Possibly even something software-side... not sure! PS: The $file variable was built by me, the filesize is that of `filesize($file['file'])` and the file does exist, as it passes the original If statement.

Comment: @RadGH I don't know what else it could be then. And please add the `@` symbol followed by name, that way I know you are addressing me and receive notification at the same time ;-)

Comment: @RadGH You say you followed an example from PHP.net. I don't see `basename` in your posted code, for example `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));` as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2400 <= in your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have created a test case for you, which streams "example.pdf" from the document root. This gives the same issue. [Direct link to PDF (no PHP)](http://abrahaojiujitsu.com/example.pdf) - [Script which streams PDF (uses PHP, doesn't work)](http://abrahaojiujitsu.com/download/?example_pdf) - [source code (image)](http://radleygh.com/images/notepad++_2013-246-15-20-42-93.png)

Comment: @RadGH Seems like it's a parameter issue from what I can tell by `http://abrahaojiujitsu.com/download/?example_pdf` there is no extension at the end.

Comment: What happens if you remove `ob_clean()` ?

Comment: I think this is caused by a `0x04` byte aka the `End-of-Transmission` character ([phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ark-1zd)). Yet I can't find any solution.

Comment: And this seem to be a Chrome-only issue.

Comment: @Glavić, that didn't seem to do anything. I've done quite a lot of basic expirementing with the code I've provided, I don't think it's a simple solution unfortunately.

Comment: @AgreeOrNot, I'm not entirely sure that's the issue, but it does seem to cut off at that particular point consistently, so it may be the best bet. Unfortunately I'm not sure how this helps me, as I don't know how to fix that. To your second comment, I do experience the same issue in Firefox and IE8 however, so I assume this is actually a server-side issue. Were you able to download and view the PDF in [this pdf](http://abrahaojiujitsu.com/download/?example_pdf) in any browser? If one browser works, it must not be the server.

Comment: I have runned your code on my localhost, and it also doesn't work. When I removed ob_clean() it started working. BTW why do you have ob_clean there?

Comment: @Glavić It's right out of the manual. I assume ob_clean() is used to clean any errors/notices that may accidentally be written before the PDF is sent, which would cause it to be an invalid file. And unfortunately removing ob_clean does not fix the issue for me. Thanks for trying, though!

Comment: @RadGH No. I tried in Chrome/FF/IE, all failed. My mistake. But I discover that when I test it on localhost, all of them are able to complete the transmission, despite that Chrome shows me a cancelled status.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread but I have the solution for everyone here.

You have a script somewhere in your application that's compressing spaces or other characters.

```
ob_start("sanitize_output");
```

That was the problem in one scenario I noticed. If you turn off the buffer reduction script (called "sanitize_output" above) then your .pdf will show up normally. That extra 2kb's you noticed that were trimmed was probably from spacing or cutting out unneeded characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: Just give $file a relative path to the file and check it.

```
<?php
// your file to download
$file = path/to/the/file;

header("Expires: 0");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$basename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

header("Content-type: application/".$ext);
// tell file size
header('Content-length: '.filesize($file));
// set file name
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$basename\"");
readfile($file);
// Exit script. So that no useless data is output-ed.
exit;
?>
```

Let php calculate the file size and date and other stuff. It is quiet possible that an error can occur while feeding it via an array.

Also in this code I have used pathinfo so as to automatically set the Content-type and file name.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute for someone that was lost with this solution.

What worked for me, has said above by @Kalob Taulien was insert these lines that turn off a compactation algorith builtin that was corrupting my files on download by the script, here is:

```
@ob_end_clean();
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) 
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
```

After insert that before fpassthru($file) function, the downloads worked well.